# How does the w3wp.exe work with a web application?

Tags: c#, iis, w3wp

If I create a web application and host it on a Windows Server, then as I understand it, IIS handles the initial request and routes it to the appropriate website or application. I'm under the impression that a w3wp.exe (worker process) instance is created for each application. IIS works with the worker process, which in turn works with the web application.

What happens if the application gets twenty requests per second? **Will the worker process create twenty instances of the application to handle each request, or will it queue the requests passing them to a single instance of the application as and when?**

I suspect it's the latter. If that is the case then am I right to think that the worker process will keep an application alive whilst it is getting requests?

I'm trying to fully understand what a web application does when it handles many con-current requests. I've tried asking this question before but struggled with the wording, so hopefully this makes sense.

**EDIT:** 
Thanks to Mason I realised that the answer was right in front of me! Web applications use DLLs, which can't run by themselves. It's the w3wp.exe (worker process) which call the DLLs to handle the requests.

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens?

Comment: From what I've seen in Performance Monitor and by watching Task Manager I only get reports on the w3wp process, not the application that the w3wp process is using.

Comment: Your questions can be answered by just looking at the running process when you have multiple requests coming in.

Comment: Am I looking in the wrong place then. When I'm on a web server looking at Task Manager and Performance Monitor I don't see anything to do with the actual application. I do see a single instance for each worker process.

Comment: W3WP is the web application. It's the executable that runs and hosts your code. So you've just answered your own question by looking at the Task Manager.

Comment: Ah, am I getting myself confused? So, if I have a site called 'myconfusion.co.uk' and host it on IIS, then I'll see a w3wp process running handling its requests. And this one instance of w3wp is the one instance of 'myconfusion.co.uk'?

Comment: Well, I'm glad I asked the question, although I feel foolish as well. If you want to post your comments as a reply I'll mark it as my accepted answer. Failing that I might delete this question since I don't think it adds much for other people. Thanks again.

Comment: It does reveal how it works. You may think it's a silly question now, but someone else may come along with the same silly question, so it's useful. As for answering it, I'll leave that to you now that you know. I just helped you along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of worker processes per web site is controlled in the application pool advanced settings (in IIS management console).

The configuration of number of concurrent requests each of the workers can handle depends on the IIS version. In IIS 7 was in the same place, for more recent versions you will have to check your `machine.config` (looking for `maxWorkerThreads`)